# In a specific column, edit rows that don't equal any of 3 possible variables, preferably in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

In a specific column, I need to replace rows with 'X', but only if they don't match any of 3 possible patterns (3 variables). Note that the column won't always be the same column, thus the code must work with the column number itself being a variable number. The same can be said for the 3 possible patterns. its difficult to explain without demonstration. in the example, if you look at column 1 and see how it changes specific ones to 'X' based on the 'GrabVariantOption's, then its probably clearer than anything I can explain.

Example input:

```
A,A,A,X
A,G,T,X
C,A,G,T
A,C,G,T
f,X,A,g
g,T,A,A
m,s,G,A
G,s,m,A
```

Example 3 possible patterns:

```
GrabVariantOption1=A
GrabVariantOption2=g
GrabVariantOption3=G
```

Some pseudo code, that is kind of the principle of what I want to do:

```
Column=1   

awk -F ',' -v a=$GrabVariantOption1 -v b=$GrabVariantOption2 -v c=$GrabVariantOption3 -v x=$Column '{$x; if NR!=a && NR!=b && NR!=c; flag=1} {if flag=1 NR==X }'
```

Example Output:

```
A,A,A,X
A,G,T,X
X,A,G,T
A,C,G,T
X,X,A,g
g,T,A,A
X,s,G,A
G,s,m,A
```

Comment: This question is not at all clear. Please explain in words how you need to transform the input into the output.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question, to make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, \
  -v "a=$GrabVariantOption1" \
  -v "b=$GrabVariantOption2" \
  -v "c=$GrabVariantOption3" \
  -v "x=$Column" '
  $x != a && $x != b && $x != c {$x = "X"}
  {print}'
```

Or here as those are single ASCII letters:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, \
  -v "pattern=^[$GrabVariantOption1$GrabVariantOption2$GrabVariantOption3]\$" \
  -v "x=$Column" '
  $x !~ pattern {$x = "X"}
  {print}'
```

`NR` is a special variable in `awk` that holds the current record number (line number here with the default record separator). `$` is an operator to dereference a field.  So if `x` is the field number `$ x` gives you the content of the `x`<sup>th</sup> field.

Comment: Brilliant!, that works great, and has also really helped improve my understanding of awk.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
awk -v col=1 -v keys="$GrabVariantOption1,$GrabVariantOption2,$GrabVariantOption3" '
    BEGIN {
        FS = OFS = ","

        # keys is a single string: "A,g,G"

        n = split(keys, a)

        # now, n=3 and a is the array ("A", "g", "G")

        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) keep[a[i]] = 1

        # now, keep is an associative array mapping "A"=>1, "g"=>1, "G"=>1
        # ("A" in keep) is true
        # ("C" in keep) is false
    }
    !($col in keep) {$col = "X"}
    {print}
' input
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
awk -F ',' -v a=$GrabVariantOption1 -v b=$GrabVariantOption2 -v c=$GrabVariantOption3 -v x=$Column -v OFS=',' '{if (($x != 'a') && ($x != 'b') && ($x != 'c')) {$x="X"}; print }' input.txt 
A,A,A,X
A,G,T,X
X,A,G,T
A,C,G,T
X,X,A,g
g,T,A,A
X,s,G,A
G,s,m,A
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to look at the pbm using Gnu sed employing extended regexes:

```
$ col=1 opt1=G opt2=g opt3=G
$ opt=${opt1}${opt2}${opt3}
$ sed -Ee "
   s/^/,/
   s/(([^,]*,){$col})[^$opt]/\1X/
   s/,//
" file.csv
```

With Perl you could do like this also:

```
$ perl -lpe "
   s/^/,/;
   substr(\$_,2*$col-1,1) =~ tr/$opt/X/c;
   s/,//;
" file.csv
```